# Declaring Variables and Using Them Later On in C#

Tags: c#, console

I'm making a text based adventure game in C# and I want the user's in-game race to be displayed at the top at all times. When the user inputs their race I want it to recognize what race they chose regardless of how they input it. EX: user inputs `o` or `orc` and output is `Orc`."

The way I have it now lets me set the variable `player_race_display` to a certain value depending on what the user inputs, but doesn't let me use the variable to actually print the value later on in the code.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {

        string player_race_display;

        //START SCREEN


        //Horizontal borders
        Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 5);
        Console.Write(" __________________________________________________________________");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 18);
        Console.Write("___________________________________________________________________");

        //Vertical borders
        for (int c = 6; c <= 18; c++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(25, c);
            Console.Write("|");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(92, c);
            Console.Write("|");
        }

        //Asking for User Input
            //Asking Name and Giving Example
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 7);
        Console.Write("Enter Name: ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 7);
        Console.Write("\"Johnny Appleseed\"");
            //Asking Race and Giving Options
        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 9);
        Console.Write("Enter Race: ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(65, 9);
        Console.Write("(O)rc (E)lf (H)uman");
            //Put in code to select attributes based on race picked (eg strength, intelligence, etc)



        //UserInputs
            //name
        Console.SetCursorPosition( 42, 7);
        string player_name = Console.ReadLine();
            //race
        Console.SetCursorPosition(42, 9);
        string player_race = Console.ReadLine();



        if (player_race == "o" || player_race == "O" || player_race == "orc" || player_race == "Orc") 
            {
                player_race_display = "Orc";
            }
        else if(player_race == "e" || player_race == "E" || player_race == "elf" || player_race == "Elf")
            {
                player_race_display = "Elf";
            }
        else if (player_race == "h" || player_race == "H" || player_race == "human" || player_race == "Human")
            {
                 player_race_display = "Human";
            }



        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

        //VISUALS WINDOW
            //Horizontal borders
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5,0);
        Console.Write(" _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 22);
        Console.Write("______________________________________________________________________________________________________________");

            //Vertical borders
        for (int a = 1; a <= 22; a++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(5, a);
            Console.Write("|");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(115, a);
            Console.Write("|");
        }

            //Border around top info
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 2);
        Console.Write(" _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________");

            //Name
        Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 1);
        Console.Write("Name: " + player_name);

            //Race
        Console.SetCursorPosition( 55, 1);
        Console.Write("Race: " + player_race_display);


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //GUI

        //Horizontal borders
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 23);
        Console.Write(" _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(5, 28);
        Console.Write("______________________________________________________________________________________________________________");

        //Vertical borders
        for (int b = 24; b<=28; b++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(5, b);
            Console.Write("|");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(115, b);
            Console.Write("|");
        }




        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Here is where I declare each variable:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(42, 9);
string player_race = Console.ReadLine();



if (player_race == "o" || player_race == "O" || player_race == "orc" || player_race == "Orc") 
{
    player_race_display = "Orc";
}
else if(player_race == "e" || player_race == "E" || player_race == "elf" || player_race == "Elf")
{
    player_race_display = "Elf";
}
else if (player_race == "h" || player_race == "H" || player_race == "human" || player_race == "Human")
{
    player_race_display = "Human";
}
```

And here is where I try to use the variable to print the choice:

```
//Race
Console.SetCursorPosition( 55, 1);
Console.Write("Race: " + player_race_display);
```

I'm getting the message:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'player_race_display'

Any help is much appreciated as I'm fairly new to programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: Ok, player_race_display is still "in scope", so there are no problems there. However, it's possible it has not been defined (been set a value) by the time you print it out. You can assign a default value in the declaration at the start of the function or add another catch-all else clause to where you are setting it to "Orc, "Elf", etc.

Comment: @JCarpet You should continue to include the error message in your question as it will help other people find it if they're having the same problem, and it is kind of required for your question to constitute a "good question".

Comment: @John Gotcha, didn't know that. I'll be sure to include that from now on, I think I just implemented your edit correctly.

Comment: @JCarpet I've added the message back for you :)

Comment: This should solve your issue `string player_race_display = null;` You have design time error, not runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error message is because not every path assigns a value to `player_race_display` before you use it.

Consider the following code:

```
string value;
int i = 2;
if (i == 0) 
{
    value = "Zero";
}
else if (i == 1)
{
    value = "One";
}
Console.WriteLine("Value is " + value);
```

Clearly `value` will never be assigned a value.

There are two ways to resolve this:

1. Assign a default value when you define it:

   `string value = "defaultValue";`
2. Assign a value in all code paths by adding an `else`:

---

```
string value;
int i = 2;
if (i == 0) 
{
    value = "Zero";
}
else if (i == 1)
{
    value = "One";
}
else
{
    value = "ElseReached";
}
Console.WriteLine("Value is " + value);
```

** Note that the default value you assign can be `null`, but be careful not to cause errors for yourself further down.

Comment: Wow I feel slightly dumb now that I see how easy it was haha. Thank you so much! Cheers